# How to get param in url of signalr routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

The mapping configration inside startup is

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<WsHub>("/ws/{id}"); // here to map "/ws/some_id"
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

and WsHub definition is

```cs
    public class WsHub : Hub
    {
        public WsHub() // here?
        {
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            // here?
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

the problem is how to get the `id` (e.g. `some_id`) in the hub?

Comment: It there not a `context` sitting on `this`? Also, which version of SignalR?

Comment: You won't get any params in `OnConnectedAsync` that is just when SignalR establishes connection. You'll get the Param through the Function that you Invoke from the Client side

Comment: the latest bundled in `asp.net core 3.1`. so I need to get it from `Context.GetHttpContext()` manually, right? I prefer something like `[FromRoute]`/`[FromQuery]` :(

Comment: Can get it from `Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Path`.